# how to set stream name for RTMP player in run time using flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, red5

Hello: here is the code of a RTMP player

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/12/14/playing-a-video-from-an-rtmp-server-using-the-spark-videoplayer-control-in-flex-4/ -->
<s:Application name="Spark_VideoPlayer_DynamicStreamingVideoSource_test"
        xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <s:VideoPlayer id="vidPlyr"
            loop="true"
            muted="true"
            left="100" right="100"
            top="100" bottom="100"
            horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
        <s:source>
            <s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource id="source" host="rtmp://fmsexamples.adobe.com/vod/" streamType="recorded">
                <s:DynamicStreamingVideoItem is="item1" streamName="mp4:_cs4promo_1000.f4v" />
            </s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource>
        </s:source>
    </s:VideoPlayer>

</s:Application>
```

How can I set the streamName in run time with as3 code ?

I tested with:

```
source.host="myRTMP";
Item1.streamName="myflv";
```

but this did not work !

It works however when parameters are embeded into the mxml

any idea ?

Comment: What class is `Item1`?  Or is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

if it works on mxml this should work on as3.
Solution 1 : set the video player parameters on creation complete event or when any other event fired like this :

```
    protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        source.host=myRTMP;
        Item1.streamName=myflv;

    }
```

Solution 2: bind your videoplayer parameters to your variables :

In MXML :

```
<s:VideoPlayer id="vidPlyr"
            loop="true"
            muted="true"
            left="100" right="100"
            top="100" bottom="100"
            horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
        <s:source>
            <s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource id="source" host="{myRTMP}"    
                streamType="recorded">
                <s:DynamicStreamingVideoItem is="item1" streamName="{myflv}" />
            </s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource>
        </s:source>
    </s:VideoPlayer>
```

IN ActionScript:

```
[Bindable] public var myRTMP:String;
[Bindable] public var myflv:String;
```

If this does'nt success verify that your stream is available

Comment: I did that with no success: black screen.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old post, but just in case someone has the same issue, Black Screen on play this Flex Bug workaround may solve the their issue.

OSMFSettings.enableStageVideo = false

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-33856